# How to include multiple Unicode ranges in a single set (class) or group of characters?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

Consider a set that includes all decimal digits and all Basic Latin lowercase characters. I want to include them in a single set (or group) using the notation for Unicode ranges. Is it possible?

I tried the following:

```
var str1 = "ABCDa0b1cdef2Zgh34ijkYXlmnopqEF";
var str2 = str1.replace(/(?:[\u30-\u39]|[\u61-\u7A])/g, "_");
console.log(str2);
```

Or this:

```
var str1 = "ABCDa0b1cdef2Zgh34ijkYXlmnopqEF";
var str2 = str1.replace(/[\u30-\u39\u61-\u7A]/g, "_");
console.log(str2);
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Do you mean `/[\u0030-\u0039\u0061-\u007A]/g`?

Comment: The two patterns work well, your problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to AND two or more character ranges, they should be just put one after another inside a single character class (or, bracket expression) with no `|` or `,` in between.

The `(?:[\u0030-\u0039]|[\u0061-\u007A])` is the same as `[\u0030-\u0039\u0061-\u007A]`.

Now, [`/[\u30-\u39\u61-\u7A]/g` regex](https://regex101.com/r/SvXu1d/1) is equal to `/[;:?[@\\<->0-9A-TuU-Z]/g` regex, so it matches:

- all ASCII digits
- all ASCII uppercase letters
- a `u` letter, `;`, `:`, `?`, `[`, `@`, `\`, `<`, `=`, `>`.

It happens because `\uXX` is an invalid escape sequence, but JS does not throw an exception and just treats the `\u` as `u`, and then parses the ranges like this:

```
\u   matches the character u literally (case sensitive)
3    matches the character 3 literally (case sensitive)
0-\u a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and u (index 117) (case sensitive)
39   matches a single character in the list 39 (case sensitive)
\u   matches the character u literally (case sensitive)
6    matches the character 6 literally (case sensitive)
1-\u a single character in the range between 1 (index 49) and u (index 117) (case sensitive)
7A   matches a single character in the list 7A (case sensitive)
```

You need to use the `\uXXXX` notation:

```js
var str1 = "~ABCDa0b1cdef2Zgh34ijkYXlmnopqEF~";
var str2 = str1.replace(/[\u0030-\u0039\u0061-\u007A]/g, "_");
console.log(str2);
```

You may use a shortened notation, `\u{XX}` with  ES6+ `u` "flagged" regexps:

```js
var str1 = "~ABCDa0b1cdef2Zgh34ijkYXlmnopqEF~";
var str2 = str1.replace(/[\u{30}-\u{39}\u{61}-\u{7A}]/ug, "_");
console.log(str2);
```

Or, this can be just written as `/[\x30-\x39\x61-\x7A]/g`.

See more [details on how to use Unicode code points in Java regexes at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_meaning_in_regular_expressions).

Comment: Yes, it works. So, it works with \xNN or \uNNNN notation, but why doesn't it work with \uNN notation?

Comment: @lyricallywicked I added more variations.

Comment: Yes. I forgot that the "\u" prefix requires not less than four hexadecimal digits after it...